# What does it mean when someone says "I shoved my ignorance in people’s faces"?

Tags: meaning

> Man, when I was young **I shoved my ignorance in people’s faces**. They beat me with sticks. By the time I was forty my blunt instrument had been honed to a fine cutting point for me. If you hide your ignorance, no one will hit you and you’ll never learn.

Does shoved my ignorance in people's faces means asking people even the smallest doubts which makes them feel we are ignorant?

Comment: Have you looked up "shove" in the dictionary?

Comment: The person quoted is saying that they made their ignorance obvious to people they interacted with, and got immediate feedback (this feedback was harsh, but apparently useful).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

To "shove something in someone's face" is to make them excessively aware of it, or draw excessive attention to it.

> John shoved his wealth in my face, talking about his big house, expensive cars and exotic vacations.

Comment: Thank you so much!